# How do initializations of C structs work in iOS's Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, c, ipad

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGSize :

```
struct CGSize {
   CGFloat width;
   CGFloat height;
};
typedef struct CGSize CGSize;
```

CGSize is an unadorned C struct and doesn't accept messages.

What are appropriate ways to (in my case) create a CGsize with its dimensions to be 0?

If I were working straight C, it would be a use case for calloc() or whatnot. What is the Objective-C idiom for this use case?

Comment: Um, Objective-C is a superset of C. You can use `calloc()`. But are you sure you need dynamic memory allocation? Why not go with the pre-defined constant `CGSizeZero`? Or `CGSize sz = { 0, 0 };`? Or `CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(0, 0);`? Or `(CGSize){ 0, 0 }`?

Comment: @H2CO3, usually the worst way to solve a problem is, for instance, frame, solve, and almost build the solution the way it works in COBOL, and then do what you can to implement the solution in Python's syntax. Anything that will work in C *will* work in Objective-C, but there is a great deal of difference between writing a Python solution that breathes Python and writing a Python solution that breathes COBOL.

Comment: @JonathanHayward Except that COBOL is not a strict superset of Python, but Objective-C is a strict superset of C. It's only a thin layer on top of C that adds some OO and nothing else, and - as you just experienced it - you can't (and shouldn't) try to "objectivize" stuff that is just plain ol' C. Also, don't teach me design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get one with 0 for both dimensions would be the constant, `CGSizeZero`

Another way would be `CGSizeMake(0,0)`

Comment: Thank you; are there generally constants and factory functions to create pure, unadorned C structs?

Comment: @JonathanHayward Generally? In what sense?

Comment: @H2CO3, in the sense of "Is my first place to look to instantiate a struct some factory (or constant) such as picciano gave?"

Comment: Lot's of them have CGFooZero, where Foo is the struct type.

Comment: @JonathanHayward In this case, yes. But you won't always find one, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

the specific case you can use

```
CGSize zeroSize = CGSizeZero;
CGSize zeroSize = (CGSize){ 0, 0 };
CGSize zeroSize = (CGSize){ .width = 0, .height = 0 };
CGSize zeroSize = CGSizeMake(0,0);
```

Keep in mind that many cases the frameworks such as Core Graphics and Core Foundation provide you with constants such as `CGSizeZero` that you can use, so you generally don't need to dynamically initialize such structs with `calloc`.